# How can I match the encoder decoder dimension of deep auto encoder?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, autoencoder

I'm coding very simple deep auto encoder with MNIST data set which have three latent space layer.
However, there are problems with the encoder and decoder dimensions.

The exact error message is : ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_2 to have shape (128,) but got array with shape (32,) at line 60.

(line 60 : decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs))

and I don't know how to solve it. I will attach my full code below. 
Please help. Thanks.

```
    from keras.layers import Input, Dense
    from keras.models import Model
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import mlab
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import sys
    np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)


    # encoding_dimensions
    encoding_dim = 128
    encoding_dim2 = 64
    encoding_dim3 = 32

    # input placeholder
    input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
    encoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_img)
    encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
    encoded = Dense(32, activation='relu')(encoded)

    decoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
    decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
    decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

    print(encoded.shape)
    print(decoded.shape)

    autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')


    encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)
    encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))


    decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
    decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))

    from keras.datasets import mnist
    (x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()

    x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.

    x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), np.prod(x_train.shape[1:])))
    x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), np.prod(x_test.shape[1:])))

    print(x_test.shape)
    print(x_train.shape)

    autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                    epochs=1,
                    batch_size=256,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_data=(x_test, x_test))

    encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(x_test)
    decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)

    n=10
    plt.figure(num=2, figsize=(20, 3))
    for i in range(n):
        # input data
        ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(x_test[i].reshape(28, 28))
        plt.gray()
        ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

        # recnstructed data
        ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1 + n)
        plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i].reshape(28, 28))
        plt.gray()
        ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the input definition of your `decoder` model. You set the input to the decoder model to be: `encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))` where `encoding_dim=128`. However, the real input to the decoder is the encoder output, which is of size 32 (the number of neurons in last `Dense` layer of the encoder). You need to fix the declaration of the input shape in the decoder model, for example:

```
encoded_input = Input(shape=(32,))
```

or mode generally:

```
encoded_input = Input(shape=encoded.shape)
```